# size_t,key_t,time_t etc

Tags: c, linux

i have encountered these "X_t" types many times in c programs,what does they really mean?where is the location of these definition?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `_t` suffix means "type"; it's not a rule that you have to use it, it's just a convention followed by a lot of standard types from the standard libraries.  They're usually defined in the header files that use them, or sometimes in header files included by those headers.

`size_t` is defined in `<stddef.h>`, and `time_t` is defined in `<time.h>`.  `key_t` is not a standard C type, so it's probably defined in the library header for whatever library it's used in.

If you want to know *exactly* which header file a definition came from, you can run the preprocessor:

```
gcc -E file.c -o file.i
```

The preprocessor output `file.i` will show you all of the nested include files.  You can then search it for the definition, then scroll upwards until you find the comment that indicates which header file it came from.

Comment: the preprocessor method for finding header files is really useful,thanks!I just wondering if "cpp" and "gcc -E ..." is the same?

Comment: "cpp" on a linux system generally invokes g++, which is not the same as gcc.

Comment: I think that the _t suffix is reserved by POSIX for future expansion. If that's really so then it's generally not a good idea to use _t as a suffix for user defined types.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a Google search with "c size_t" which gave [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/size_t/) first link. time_t information is on that site as well. Once you get that information, it's a small step to realize that key_t must be following the same pattern.